# Simplicity Itself?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

Usual format: each ellipse represents an as-yet-unknown category. Each tile belongs in at least one ellipse - but which ones where and why?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the Venn diagram should be resolved like so:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

Where the two ellipses represent:

> Left - Can be **followed by a city name**:
>  [Dion **DUBLIN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dion_Dublin), [Irving **BERLIN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irving_Berlin), [Isaiah **WASHINGTON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Washington), [Whitney **HOUSTON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_Houston).
>
>  Right - Can be **preceded by a city name**:
>  **WELLINGTON** Boots, [**WASHINGTON** Irving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Irving), [**SINGAPORE** Sling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Sling), [**FLORENCE** Welch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Welch)
>
>  Hence 'Irving' appears in the intersection.
>
>  (Note: Here, I have chosen just what I would consider the most famous connections. It is possible to find further more obscure entries which still have their own Wikipedia pages, like [**CHARLOTTE** Whitney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlotte_Anita_Whitney), which if we were to include it would see Whitney moved to the intersection. However, as per the title, I have opted for *simplicity* here...)

Note from the title...

> the hidden hint word 'city' in SIMPLI**CITY**.

Comment: Quicker than Planck time! Chapeau